# How to get all product prices from a website with curl

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

Im trying to use cURL to get all the product prices from this site but i dont really know how to scrape all prices for every product on this site http://www.bikestore.ie/.

can someone please give me som tips?

Right now im just testing to get one price for a product and that is no problem, butt can i get the precis for all products??

my code right now is:

```
 public function Scrape(){

    $curl = curl_init('http://www.bikestore.ie/scott-speedster-30-bike-2015.html');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $page = curl_exec($curl);

    if(!empty($curl)){

        $doc = new DOMDocument;
        $doc->loadHTML($page);

        $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
        $rupees = $xpath->evaluate('string(//div[@class="product-shop"]//div[@class="price-box"]//span[@class="price"])');
        echo $rupees;
    }
    else {
        print "Not found";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an easy task.
The site is structutred. But each product is defined in url.
ex.: http://www.bikestore.ie/scott-speedster-30-bike-2015.html
when you add it to cart the unique product identifier is seen:[image]

### Steps

1. Crawl the whole site with cURl (find all the links `<a>` of products). See the post on [simple python crawler](http://scraping.pro/simple-email-crawler-python/), you just make similar with php.
2. Store them in DB (ex. MySQL)
3. For each link you run your `Scrape()` procedure fetching price/product id. Getting price of a product you mark its link as 'checked' in DB so that you do not run it once again.

Notes: For the sake of parallel processing you might run processes of **point 1&2** and of **point 3** in parallel. Use cron for this.